# Como acessar propriedades de um objeto que está salvo dentro do array?

Tags: javascript, banco-de-dados, indexeddb

```
var objectStore = db.transaction(3).objectStore(3);
    var customers = [];
    
    objectStore.openCursor().onsuccess = event => {
    
      var cursor = event.target.result;
       
       if (cursor) {
           var key = cursor.key;
           var value = cursor.value;

            customers.push(value);
          
          
             log(customers[0].nome);
           
           
             cursor.continue();
          
           }else {
          log(customers);
       }  
       
     
         };
    
    };
```

Até aqui o código me retorna o valor da propriedade nome, mas se eu mudar a chave do array de 0 para 1 por exemplo já não consigo mais recuperar o valor.

```
Array
(3) [{…}, {…}, {…}]
0: {idade: '500', nome: '500', id: 1}
1: {idade: '0', nome: '0', id: 2}
2: {idade: '700', nome: '538', id: 3}
```

o resultado se eu alterar customers[0].nome para customers[1].nome é esse:

```
gerarPDF.html:741 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'idade')
at objectStore.openCursor.onsuccess (gerarPDF.html:741:23)
```

Answer (score 0):

O índice 0 existe pois no momento em que você o chama ele certamente já foi definido por ter feito um `customers.push(value)` logo antes. Na primeira iteração ele sempre existirá, por isso somente o índice `0` funciona. Já o índice `1` na primeira iteração não vai existir, pois ainda não terá sido definido, por isso o erro se você alterá-lo ali.

A solução seria alterar a linha ali do log para usar o próprio value, já que você precisa acessar o valor atual da iteração:

```
var objectStore = db.transaction(3).objectStore(3);
var customers = [];

objectStore.openCursor().onsuccess = event => {

  var cursor = event.target.result;
   
   if (cursor) {
       var key = cursor.key;
       var value = cursor.value;

        customers.push(value);
      
      
         log(value.nome);
       
       
         cursor.continue();
      
       }else {
      log(customers);
   }  
   
 
     };

};
```

Comment: obrigado Wallace Magalhães você ajudou bastante.

Comment: sua explicação tirou muitas duvidas valeu mesmo.

Comment: Imagina! Fico a disposição. Peço por gentileza que avalie minha resposta, positiva ou negativamente, com base no quanto ela foi útil para você. =]

Answer (score -2):

Para conseguir obter o resultado que eu esperava fiz da seguinte forma:

```
var objectStore = db.transaction(3).objectStore(3);
    var customers = [];
    
    objectStore.openCursor().onsuccess = event => {
    
      var cursor = event.target.result;
       
       if (cursor) {
       
           
           var value = cursor.value;
           
           let rpm = value.idade;
           let artigo = value.nome;

          customers.push(rpm, artigo);
          
          
          // log(customers[1]);
           
           
           cursor.continue();
          
       }else {
          log(customers);
       }
```

Criei duas variáveis, rpm e artigo para receberem do banco de dados os valores referentes a idade e nome, e em seguida com o método PUSH insiro esses valores dentro do array customers[];